# How to serve a socket from a Java EE application?

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee, jboss

We would like to serve some client requests within our Java EE application server (JBoss 4.2.3). I read that the [Java EE spec doesn't allow opening a socket from an enterprise bean](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/guidelines/designing_enterprise_applications/ejb_tier/qanda/restrictions.html). But the spec suggests no alternatives.

> Specifically, enterprise beans should not:
>
> - listen on, accept connections on, or multicast from a network socket

So the question is: What can I do to serve some **binary** tcp based protocols (not http) from within an application server?

[Here](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=10374) someone suggests to implement a [resource adapter](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/connectorclient/resourceadapter.html). Is this the way you have to go or are there other (easier) solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now I implement a workaround:

[alt text http://yuml.me/7f82bd5c](http://yuml.me/7f82bd5c)

I use a standalone java application that accepts tcp calls from the client and forwards them as JNDI calls to the application server.

Comment: Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) you usually make lookup calls, you could lookup an ejb and make remote calls to process the data received from your standalone server.

Comment: Link is not accessible anymore

Answer (score 7):

You're right, since you can declare transactions for every thing in Java EE they must be supported from all components you want to connect. Files if any should be stored in a database. Everything should be controlled by the container, because it the only way to have a scaling application using Java EE.

A few options:

- Implement a Connector (JCA) a example is here: 
  http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/article.tss?l=J2EE1_4
  probably the best way if you have existing clients.
- Use Java Message Queues
- The relationship between this techniques is discussed here
  http://java.sun.com/products/jms/faq.html#relship_ejbs
- Write server who stores requests in the database.(No Tx support)
- If you have only one server and it seems too much overhead, you could ignore these
  aspects and follow Vinegars suggestion. But if you need Tx later or additional nodes
  this part has to be redesigned.

Comment: note that this JCA example is for JCA 1.5 and the article is from 2003. This covers JCA 1.6 included in javaEE 6, that version is a lot less XML-loving: http://www.oraclejavamagazine-digital.com/javamagazine/20120910/?pg=56&pm=1&u1=friend#pg56

Comment: I'm trying a bean with Singleton and Startup and serializing events through Messages. After @pgras remarked "That in mind nothing will halt you from starting a server socket in your app" it sounds pretty safe.

Comment: @stuartw No....don't ever do that. You are in direct violation of the spec. From the EJB3.0 spec directly (section 21.1.2): `An enterprise bean must not attempt to listen on a socket, accept connections on a socket, or use a socket for multicast.` http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-oth-JSpec/ejb-3_0-fr-spec-ejbcore.pdf?AuthParam=1540507489_8296fcddc15d6af8a10ede3d2d129c53

Answer (score 2):

Neither should you access files :(

This is in the spec because EJBs have to be:

- distributable (you don't know beforehand on what server/instance your EJB will be deployed
- the container is to be able to manage "everything" so you must not spawn your own threads

That in mind nothing will halt you from starting a server socket in your app (the best place would probably be in a servlet) but you should take care about how the serversocket is closed when your app goes down...

Answer (score 0):

I have used somewhat similar solution as per my need in Spring MVC. Might be this can help someone here around.

Start a Socket Port on server start up. I used @scheduler annotation whereas you can use listener based solution as well. You can also implement ApplicationContextAware listener and can access other application beans from it.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365) 
public void startListenerPort() { 
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(9999); 
    // do some stuff here 
}
```

Just make sure that you have allowed TCP traffic on the port that you have assigned to the Socket (Firewall Settings).

In this way, you can have TCP traffic on port 9999, where as your app server will continue to run on different port as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Although not strictly a purely TCP connection, but you may be able to achieve what you need with a `@ServerEndpoint` annotation to create a WebSocket from the Java EE7 spec.

Although this DOES use HTTP, it will function a little bit like a binary interface when your `@OnMessage` method and a `ByteBuffer` (or `byte[]`) as the argument.