# Why JNDI resource can only be called once in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jndi

When I was learning [how to use JNDI resources in Tomcat 7](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html), a customized bean factory has been made, called `MyBeanFactory`. It provides external resources to my web application. At the first time, we assume that it provides the current system timestamp.

However, I realised that `MyBeanFactory` was called only once, at the first request. It seems that the java bean `MyBean` had be stored in Tomcat after the first execution. Then `MyBean` is reused by every request. No matter when I retape the URL in browser, the response always showed the same timestamp as the first one. Here're a list of elements that might help :

- **MyBean**: the bean provided by `MyBeanFactory`
- **MyBeanFactory**: the factory implementing `javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory`
- **context.xml**: the context descriptor for resources, located in META-INF folder
- **web.xml**: deployment descriptor
- **MyAction**: the http servlet
- **console**

Could somebody tell me why `MyBeanFactory` is called only once and if it is possible to change this feature ? Because I need to modify the factory to establish a socket with another process in the server. See [How to serve a socket from a Java EE application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063364/how-to-serve-a-socket-from-a-java-ee-application#answer-2064579)

---

**MyBean**

```
public class MyBean {

    private String foo = "Default Foo";
    private long bar = 0;

    public String getFoo() { return (this.foo); }
    public void setFoo(String foo) { this.foo = foo; }      
    public long getBar() { return (this.bar); }
    public void setBar(long bar) { this.bar = bar; }

}
```

**MyBeanFactory**

```
public class MyBeanFactory implements ObjectFactory {

    @Override
    public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context nameCtx,
            Hashtable<?, ?> environment) throws NamingException {
        System.out.println("MyBeanFactory starts");
        MyBean bean = new MyBean();
        bean.setBar(System.currentTimeMillis());
        // Return the customized instance
        return bean;

    } 
}
```

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context
  path="/jndi"
  reloadable="true"
  cachingAllowed="false"
  antiResourceLocking="true">

  <Resource 
    name="bean/MyBeanFactory"
    auth="Container"
    type="com.mycompany.MyBean"
    factory="com.mycompany.MyBeanFactory"
    bar="23"/>

</Context>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  id="WebApp_ID"
  version="3.1">

  <display-name>jndi</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mycompany.MyAction</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <!--
      Apache Tomcat 7: JNDI Resources HOW-TO
      https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html
   -->
  <resource-env-ref>
    <description>
      Object factory for MyBean instances.
    </description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>
      bean/MyBeanFactory
    </resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>
      com.mycompany.MyBean
    </resource-env-ref-type>
  </resource-env-ref>
</web-app>
```

**MyAction**

```
public class MyAction extends HttpServlet {

    // ...

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("doGet");
        response.getWriter()
            .append("Hello coming from ")
            .append(request.getRequestURI());

        Context initCtx = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("initCtx");
            initCtx = new InitialContext();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Context envCtx = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("envCtx");
            envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MyBean bean;
        try {
            System.out.println("lookup");
            bean = (MyBean) envCtx.lookup("bean/MyBeanFactory");
            response.getWriter()
                .append("foo = " + bean.getFoo() + ", ")
                .append("bar = " + bean.getBar() + ";");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("------");
    }
}
```

**Console**

```
Dec 28, 2015 7:41:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 412 ms
doGet
initCtx
envCtx
lookup
MyBeanFactory starts  // called only once
------
doGet
initCtx
envCtx
lookup
------
doGet
initCtx
envCtx
lookup
------
```

Comment: Since you are defining a servlet context resource, it seems reasonable to expect that a given context will have only one instance.  The whole point of context resources is to be shared.  With that said, you have thrown me off a bit by referencing Tomcat 7, but using configuration attributes that are not documented by that version of Tomcat.  Which version are you actually using?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm using tomcat 8.0.21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<Resource>` element you present has attributes beyond those [documented by Tomcat 8](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource_Definitions), specifically "factory" and "bar".  Perhaps the former attribute is erroneously omitted from the docs, however, because some of the examples use it.

In any event, I would like to draw your attention to the "singleton" attribute.  When the value of that attribute is `true` (the default), the resource is treated as a singleton, with a single instance maintained by the context and shared among all users.  This seems to be the behavior you describe.  If you add that attribute to your declaration, with value `false`, then each lookup of that resource should retrieve a new instance.