# How to implement a socket for a Java EE application in Tomcat

Tags: java, python, sockets, tomcat, interprocess

I've a Python application for data analysis and a Java EE application for web monitoring. Now I need to establish a durable communication between them, in order to transfer the analysis result from python to java.

Since both of the applications are located at the same server, I want to implement a TCP socket. As for the data volume, there're about 10 sensors' data transferred per second. I'm using Tomcat 8.0 for Java EE and a simple script for python. So my questions are :

- Is socket implementation a good idea ?
- If yes, how to implement it, can somebody give me a tutorial or example ?
- If not, what should I do next ?

---

**Additional information**

I saw a related question on StackOverflow [How to serve a socket from a Java EE application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063364), there're some propositions :

- Implement a Connector (JCA). But I think the target runtime is JBoss rather than Tomcat.
- Implement a Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI). That's what I'm trying as you can see as my previous question [Why JNDI resource can only be called once in Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499922) People use JNDI for using resources, e.g. db connection. So I'm not sure if it's a good way for realtime communication. And I've met many troubles by learning it.
- I thought about web-socket. But does it mean I need a python server as well ?

Comment: No Python would be the client so you'd need a python websocket client module of some sorts. But more likely you want to make the browser the client by doing it from Javascript using socket.io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a hundred way to do it to share data between these technologies. But for Java you should keep it simple. In Tomcat you don't need to write a socket implementation, you just need a basic [Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html) implementation.  So basically for your questions.

> Is socket implementation a good idea ?

Shortly NO.

> If yes, how to implement it, can somebody give me a tutorial or
>   example ?

Already answered NO.

> If not, what should I do next ?

Write a basic servlet application who listen an server url address. Your phyton script is just a client. In phyton site you just send a POST request to servlet url and in Java side get the request read your data and process it. You can start to learn Servlet from [Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/).

Comment: It's really a great solution !!